# Parsing Json with no index

Tags: python, json, dictionary

that looks like

```
[
  {
   "userId": "jacob.smith@jacob.com",
   "firstname": "Jacob",
   "lastname": "Smith",
   "state": "ACTIVE",
   "ibmUniqueId": "someID",
   "email": "jacob.smith@jacob.com",
   "phonenumber": "3037773456",
   "id": "someID",
   "uaaGuid": "someGuid",
   "accountId": "someAccountID",
   "role": "MEMBER",
   "invitedOn": "",
   "photo": ""
 },
some other user etc
]
```

So I'm working on converting this monster bash script I wrote over to python because its getting a little too wild in bash and I feel that python offers some better handling for the complexity that I'm pulling off in bash.
So as I take this crash course on enhancing my python skills I'm now stuck.

Here is my code

```
command = "ibmcloud account users --output json"
j = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
for (k, v) in j.items():
    print("Key: " + k)
    print("Value: " +str(v))
```

As you can see from the json there is nothing that directly specifies a top level index that I can put in ['someindex']['userId'] and pull back all of the userId's.  Thats the main thing I want right now is to take all of the userId's and slam them into a variable or something that I can loop through.  But I've tried every answer I've been able to dig up here on Stack and I keep running into various issues such as 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' (for this I put the [0] but of course that only returns the first value)
or AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'userId'

Thank you all for your help with this.  I'm sure its something stupid.  Most of the json I've worked with at least has a parent index that I can reference and then go from there. 
When I was using jq for this it was just simply

```
jq -r '.[].userId'
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `[x['userId'] for x in json_data]`?

Comment: yep thats all I'm really looking for I just want to pull back all of the userIds

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension for this:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
    ['ibmcloud', 'account', 'users', '--output', 'json'])
json_data = json.loads(output)
user_ids = [obj['userId'] for obj in json_data]

print('Got user IDs: {!r}'.format(user_ids))
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  Perhaps I just wasn't using my google foo properly for what I was attempting to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an itemgetter:

```
import operator
list(map(operator.itemgetter('userId'), j))
```

Comment: well thats a neat tool

Comment: yup. it's awesome isnt?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the dict from the list:

```
j = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
for (k, v) in j[0].items(): # access the 0 index of the containing list
    print("Key: " + k)
    print("Value: " +str(v))
```

so if you have a list of dicts:

```
j = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
for i in range(len(j)):
    for (k, v) in j[i].items():
        print("Key: " + k)
        print("Value: " +str(v))
```

Comment: Python is not C, use range-based `for` loop instead of dummy indices (like `i` in your snippet)

Comment: Why, just to be more 'Pythonic'?